# write json with format in pyspark

Tags: json, pandas, pyspark, format, aws-glue

I want to write a data frame as a json dataframe in pyspark replicating this way to write json from pandas:

```
df.to_json(orient='columns')
```

then I got

```
'{"col 1":{"row 1":"a","row 2":"c"},"col 2":{"row 1":"b","row 2":"d"}}'
```

But when I use this in AWS GLUE

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').json(path)
```

I got this format:

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
'[{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"
```

I was finding out about parameters of json in pyspark and there is not orient to set the json format

Comment: A pandas data frame is designed to behave like a dictionary, and that is not the case for spark data frames. A spark data frame is more like a list. Also, remember that a spark data frame is partitioned/distributed, so the output wouldn't necessarily make sense.